# Resharper uses different code style than Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, formatting, resharper, visual-studio-2017

I am using VS2017 RC to write C# and have lately added Resharper Ultimate. However, Resharper Ultimate seems to ignore the code style I have set in Visual Studio and instead use another (probably the default C#) code style. Since Resharper often auto applies its code style, this is very annoying. I verified that it is indeed resharper by doing this:

Select some code, hit `Edit -> Advanced -> Format Selection`:
This is the visual studio formatter and it formats my code as desired
Select some code, hit `Alt+Enter -> Format Selection`:
This is Resharper's format command, and it messes up my codestyle.

So my questions are:

1. How can I tell resharper to use VS's code style?
2. If this is not possible, then where can I change the code style that resharper uses, so I can at least adjust the code style manually.
3. Why does Resharper have its own code style in the first place? Wouldn't it make a lot more sense to always use VS's code style?

Answer (score 0):

As for question #3:

> Why does Resharper have its own code style in the first place? Wouldn't it make a lot more sense to always use VS's code style?

I haven't compared the features of Resharper with recent Visual Studio versions in depth, but compared with older versions such as VS2010, the Resharper formatting engine is light-years ahead. Much more settings and flexibility to accomplish the formatting you want (and many sane defaults though that could be a matter of opinion of course). It has been enhanced even more in the 2017/2018 releases.

Resharper can also save the formatting settings to several layers of shared configuration files (committed to VCS) to make sure everyone automatically follows the same rules. This also allows for different rules to apply for different projects.